# implement redirect in android app after login

Tags: android, aws-amplify

Hi everyone I am implementing Amazon known in my project but a step is not clear to me. It is required to enter this code block for access via web UI (for social)

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.activities.HostedUIRedirectActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

for  `<data android:scheme="myapp://" />` a URI is required to bring the user back to MainActivity after login

Comment: Try adding `host`  inside `data` tag `<data
                    android:host="myapp.page.link"
                    android:scheme="https" />`

Comment: The documentation reports  `myapp://callback/` and `myapp://signout/` I have already tried this solution and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<intent-filter>
  ...
  <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="callback" />
  <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="signout" />
</intent-filter>
```